# Where did this boy come from in The Nun?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-conjuring-universe, the-nun

In *The Nun*, It occurs to Father Burke that he can enter the castle through the delivery entrance. Just before he hears the bell, he looks at the delivery door. As the camera pans from him to the door, there is a boy standing beside him who turns to look at Father Burke.

I assume this is an editing error since the only boy in the story is a possessed child from his past and he'd been fighting him in earlier scenes. The boy in THIS moment is completely passive and his presence doesn't make sense. If he is the possessed boy, why is he suddenly there for a split second in a passive manner? If he isn't that boy, where did he come from? I feel like there must be a deleted scene and this moment is a remnant.

Comment: you sure the boy wasn't there to add to the scare factor? What makes you think it was an editing error?

Comment: That boy is from his past. When he performed a failed exorcism on him which led to his death no?

Comment: KharoBangdo, I assume that is the boy... but the split second he's barely seen doesn't fit the story line.

Comment: DustinDavis, if you watch that scene you'll see that the boy isn't focused on and is out of context.

Answer (score 1):

Showing the audience brief glimpses of something that the characters themselves aren't seeing is pretty typical, especially in the horror genre (showing a ghost/entity standing behind a character that they never notice, etc). It's likely that's what it was instead of an editing error. They do show the demon tormenting the priest in the shape of the boy he couldn't save, so it was likely the same thing in that scene.